# Accepted_nested_attributes_for relation for has_many in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got the following order_params:

```
 {"user_id":"1","order_status_id":"1","delivery_type_id":"1","delivery_time":"10","order_items":[{"count":"5","item_id":"1"}]}
```

These params are used for creating an Order object with nested order_item objects. Models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :user, :order_status, :delivery_type, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :order_status
  belongs_to :delivery_type

  has_many :order_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items

end
```

Order_item:

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :item, :order, :count, presence: true
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :order
end
```

But when I'm trying to create a new Order:

```
Order.create!(order_params)
```

I got the following error:

```
OrderItem(#70182455585540) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70182454696760)
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your form for order

Comment: There is no form, I create API for mobile app. Look at the params hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You key for `order_items` attributes is wrong, which should be `order_items_attributes` if you use nested attributes.

```
...,"order_items":[{"count":"5","item_id":"1"}]}
```

should be

```
...,"order_items_attributes":[{"count":"5","item_id":"1"}]}
```

Comment: Yes, it's true. But now I've got the error: "Validation failed: Order items order cant be blank". Is it because I use validation of present order in OrderItem?

Comment: @malcoauri It's ok to remove it.